# Does order matter on the =~ operator?

Tags: ruby, regex, operators

Is there any difference besides coding style for the following two statements?

`/regex/ =~ "some_string_with_regex"`

`"some_string_with_regex" =~ /regex/`

Comment: Check out `Regexp#=~` and `String#=~` using ri.

Comment: Never knew about that tool. Thanks!

Comment: It's very handy. Check out a simple `ri =~` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference. As mentioned on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001232

> If `=~` is used with a regexp literal with named captures, captured
>   strings (or nil) is assigned to local variables named by the capture
>   names.

```
/(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<rhs>\w+)/ =~ "  x = y  "
p lhs    #=> "x" 
p rhs    #=> "y"
```

> ...
>
> The assignment is not occur if the regexp is placed at right hand
>   side.

```
"  x = y  " =~ /(?<lhs>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<rhs>\w+)/
p lhs, rhs # undefined local variable
```

[String#~=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001135)

Comment: Using block quoting made the `<lhs>` and the like disappear.